# Use variable name as part of its value js

Tags: javascript, variables

Can I get variable name when setting its value in js?

Somthing like this:

```
var js = '<span id="'+ ::self.name +'"></span>';
```

So it would be

```
 js = '<span id="js"></span>';
```

Context is not important, I know lots of longer ways to do the same, but it could be great to use the shortest.

Comment: From this alone, no. If you could give some more context to it, there could be some alternatives given though.

Comment: While it may be interesting, I think it's not useful - or please show a use-case for this

Comment: You may use server-side rendering: var <% echo variable name %> = "<% echo variable name %>";

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please paste more real code from your project?

Answer (score 2):

Mmm - the closest thing I can think of is creating via templates :

[**Example**](http://jsbin.com/ExUrATA/2/edit)

```
    //using this small template js code
    if (!String.prototype.supplant) {
        String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
            return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
                function (a, b) {
                    var r = o[b];
                    return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
                }
            );
        };
    }



var spanTmpl=  '<span id="{id}"></span>';


var a= spanTmpl.supplant({id:"js"});
var b= spanTmpl.supplant({id:"bla"});


console.log(a); //<span id="js"></span> 
console.log(b);//<span id="bla"></span>
```

Comment: Actually I need this in creating lots of templates out of array. Create even more templates to create template is not a good solution.

Comment: As I said : " the closest thing I can think of is "..... what you're asking is called reflection which js does not support.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to define a property in your js-object - i.e a name-property.

What's possible is to do the converse thing: You can call a JS-object with the name.

For example:

```
var propName = "prop";
var prop = "value";
console.log(window[propName]) // => will output "value"
```

Edit:
Have you ever looked in to a Library such as Backbone, or KnockoutJS? I'm not sure what you're doing, but my best guess is that you're building functionality those libraries are already providing...

Comment: Sure, I've worked with bb and knockout. Not the case.